# mongodb $lookup not using hash index for a simple equi join

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection called songs_test and it has a field "artist_name". I have created a hashed index on the same.

```
> db.songs_test.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "songs_new.songs_test"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "artist_name" : "hashed"
        },
        "name" : "artist_name_hashed",
        "ns" : "songs_new.songs_test"
    }
]
```

Then, I run the following aggregation query:

```
use songs_new

db.songs_test.explain().aggregate([
        {$lookup : {
                 "from": "songs_test",
                 "localField": "artist_name",
                 "foreignField": "artist_name",
                 "as": "artist_name_matches"
                 }
        },
        {$unwind : "$artist_name_matches"}
], {allowDiskUse: true}
)
```

It takes about 13min to run this aggregation query. Songs_test collection has 1 million records. When I do an explain - I see that the lookup is not using the index.

Explain output:

```
switched to db songs_new
{
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {

                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "songs_new.songs_test",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {

                    },
                    "queryHash" : "8B3D4AB8",
                    "planCacheKey" : "8B3D4AB8",
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "songs_test",
                "as" : "artist_name_matches",
                "localField" : "artist_name",
                "foreignField" : "artist_name",
                "unwinding" : {
                    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I have tried various things (suggested on the web) but couldn't find out the exact reason. Also, it takes about 13 minutes to run on an 8thread 64GB RAM machine. The aggregate query uses only a single thread (which is weird as well). 
Can someone help as to why it's not using the index and why does aggregation runs on a single thread?

Comment: Intersting question. Can you please answer
1. Why is your purpose behind using `$lookup`? 
2. What was your purpose behind indexing `artist_name` with `hashed` type?